# sqlldr corrupts my primary key after the first commit

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Sqlldr is corrupting my primary key index after the first commit in my ctl file.  After the first, no matter what I set the rows value to in my control file, I get:

```
ORA-39776: fatal Direct Path API error loading table PE_OWNER.CLINICAL_CODE
ORA-01502: index 'PE_OWNER.CODE_PK' or partition of such index is in unusable state
SQL*Loader-2026: the load was aborted because SQL Loader cannot continue.
```

I'm using Oracle database and client 11.1.0.6.0.

I know the issue is not due to duplicate rows because if I set the rows directive to a huge value, the index is not corrupt after sqlldr does a single commit for the entire file.  This provides me with a workaround, but it's still a little alarming...

Thanks for any guidance anyone can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue was that Oracle did not have time to rebuild the indices on the table in question, so I increased the batch commit size to a number larger than the number of records I was importing.

That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use SQL*Loader much on production tables, but from what I've read, you need to use conventional load.

from the [SQL*Loader documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_modes.htm#g1023818)

> **When to Use a Conventional Path Load**
>
> If load speed is most important to
>   you, you should use direct path load
>   because it is faster than conventional
>   path load. However, certain
>   restrictions on direct path loads may
>   require you to use a conventional path
>   load. You should use a conventional
>   path load in the following situations:
>
> ```
> * When accessing an indexed table concurrently with the load, or when
>   applying inserts or updates to a nonindexed table concurrently with the
>   load
> ```
>
> To use a direct path load (with the exception of parallel loads),
>   SQL*Loader must have exclusive write
>   access to the table and exclusive
>   read/write access to any indexes.